# How to return a class object?

Tags: java

*I have seen ArrayList examples but I want to know how to add objects guitar and ukulele to array i.
And also, how to return the object which has the highest number of strings?*

```
public class Demo{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
            Instrument guitar = new Instrument("Guitar", 6);
            Instrument ukulele = new Instrument("Ukulele", 4);
    
            Instrument i[] = new Instrument[2];
    
            // Adding objects guitar and ukulele to class array i
    
            // Returning object with maximum number of strings
    
        }
    }
    
    class Instrument{
    
        private String name;
        private int numOfStrings;
    
        public Instrument(String name, int numOfStrings){
    
            this.name = name;
            this.numOfStrings = numOfStrings;
        }
    
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getStrings() {
            return numOfStrings;
        }
        public void setStrings(int numOfStrings) {
            this.numOfStrings = numOfStrings;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "class object"?  Can you add details to the question to explain better?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking for this:

```
// Adding objects guitar and ukulele to class array i
   i[0] = guitar;
   i[1] = ukulele;

// Returning object with maximum number of strings
   int max = i[0].getStrings();
   for (Instrument inst : i) {
       if(inst.getStrings() > max)
       max = inst.getStrings();
    }
    System.out.println(max);
```

First of all assign the objects to the array. Then iterate them keeping track of the highest value. I suggest you to study deeper the basics of Java to solve this simple problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code showing the implementation you were asking about, hope it helps (I'd suggest looking more at object and array fundamentals)

```
public class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Instrument guitar = new Instrument("Guitar", 6);
        Instrument ukulele = new Instrument("Ukulele", 4);

        Instrument i[] = new Instrument[2];

        // Since you declared your array with empty elements, you'll have to get the current element and set the new vals manually (or use iteration)
        i[0] = guitar;
        i[1] = ukulele;
        //Alternatively, you could initialise your array with the values already set like this
        Instrument arr[] = new Instrument[] {guitar, ukulele};

        // Returning object with maximum number of strings
        Instrument highestStrung = getHighestStrungInstrument(arr);

        System.out.println("Highest: " + highestStrung.getName());

    }

    private static Instrument getHighestStrungInstrument(Instrument[] arr){

        //Var to hold current highest strings
        int highestStrings = 0;
        //Var to hold the obj with the current highest strings
        Instrument currentHighest = null;

        //loop through all the objects in the array
        for(Instrument inst : arr)
            //compare the current instrument's strings with that of the var's val
            if(inst.getStrings() > highestStrings){
                //set the new highest
                currentHighest = inst;
                highestStrings = inst.getStrings();
            }

        //Return the highest obj (Keep in mind that the val could be null)
        return currentHighest;
    }
}

class Instrument{

    private String name;
    private int numOfStrings;

    public Instrument(String name, int numOfStrings){

        this.name = name;
        this.numOfStrings = numOfStrings;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getStrings() {
        return numOfStrings;
    }
    public void setStrings(int numOfStrings) {
        this.numOfStrings = numOfStrings;
    }
}
```